# Find number of duplicate columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, both with a column called TestID.

Table 1 has 4000 rows
Table 2 has 1000 rows.

I would like to see how many rows in table 2 have the same value in the TestID column compared to table 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess at what you're expecting:

```
select count(t2.testId) T2Matches
from t1 join t2 on t1.TestId = t2.TestId;
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. I suspected each row in Table 2 corresponded with a row in table 1. When I ran this it came back as 1,000 matches (well the actual number I was hoping to see). My actual data contained 4,000,000+ rows and 1,000,000+ rows in the second table.